# -12v Regulator selection & conversion

Tags: arduino, amplifier, voltage-regulator, schematics, power-electronics

I need help in selecting proper Regulator for regulator IC for exiting hall effect sensor.Sensor exitation voltgae is +12 to -12 v . Usually i use 7812 1A for exite +12v , I would like to know is there any IC aailable which produce -12v with DIP package. Input voltage 24v.

I thought of using inverting amplifier circuit to produce -12v,I am not sure how much current can provide after conversion.

And out put of sensor mentioned as 25mA. How i can convert 0~5v range for arduino analog out. Since sensor output is current How could i convert it to 0~5v range.[image: Electrical specification]

Comment: For -12v, you may look http://www.ti.com/product/lm7912. But you need a negative input voltage.

Comment: yes ; i already seen it. Since i have only provision for +ve supply. so i asked question here

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a negative voltage input, then you will need some sort of DC to DC converter to generate it.  Depending on how much current you need, you might be able to get away with a simple charge pump, or you may need something a bit more complicated.  You can generally buy complete DC to DC converter modules that you can solder on to your board if you don't care to design one yourself.

As for rescaling the signal, there are a few ways to do that.  One method that I have seen is to use a voltage divider where you hang the 'low' end to +2.5v (or similar) instead of ground.  Another method is to build a summing amplifier where you can add the input voltage (possibly scaled down in a voltage divider) with an offset to rescale and shift it into the ADC input range.  So long as the circuit maps zero, full scale low, and full scale high to points within the ADC range, you can correct any offsets in software.  Just make sure that most of the ADC input range is covered, otherwise you won't get good resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Texas Instruments has a selection of inverting buck converters [here](http://webench.ti.com/wb5/PQS.jsp?&isPqsHome=true&expCriteria=true&vinRadio=1a&userVin=24&userVout1=-12&userIout1=.05&&efPT=1000064&cfPT=1000662&cfPT=1000661&cfPT=1001647&cfPT=1000400&cfPT=1000527&cfPT=1002030&cfPT=1000720&cfPT=1000689&cfPT=1000404&cfPT=1000100&cfPT=1000690&cfPT=1000394&cfPT=1001992&cfPT=1000685&cfPT=1000462&familyId=64&showAdditionalParameters=no&compare=yes&download=yes&sort=yes&customize=yes&paramResults=yes&paramCriteria=no&familyTree=no&military=&baSystem=yes&sortOption=&sortMode=&pageId=64&templateId=2&navigationId=11354&family=analog&military=&contentType=4&undefined&uiTemplateId=PQS_RESULTS_T&callingTemplateId=POWER_HOME_T) which will get you a negative voltage from your 24V supply. Use a 7912L to regulate the negative voltage (if you need to) and that should do it.

Comment: Thanks , but cost wise it expensive. I checked price in element14 where it cost 1300RS & it not even solderable like Dip tqfp packages

Answer (score 0):

A (simple) amplifier cannot (generally) output voltages outside the supply rails but you could set (with resistors or similar) the output of a spare amp to -12V if you had one with a negative supply (below -12V) and use it as a low current reference voltage.

A previous boss used a circuit with just one CMOS hex inverter IC (cannot be HC or HCT version type matters because it had to drive outputs hard rail to rail and handle 15V), part number escapes me just now.

The design was used to generate -12V from +12V for RS-232 line drivers.

One gate was used to make an oscillator and the other 5 were used to buffer the signal and drive a small two diode and cap charge pump configured as an inverter.  The link below is a very similar circuit I found  via Google but you would at least have to turn the diodes the other way to invert the voltage, it is arranged as a voltage doubler in the example and uses 5V components.

http://www.next.gr/uploads/7/%2B5v%2BPowered%2BCharge%2BPump%2BBattery%2BCharger.bmp

To get 5V from a 25mA signal you use a 200 Ohm burden or load resistor.  If your input can be negative 25mA as well you need to use something to shift the signal up after it is converted to a voltage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [MC34063](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC34063A-D.PDF) to generate 12V at something like 100mA maximum. **Follow the design equations in the datasheet** for your each situation to calculate the component values. The circuit will be similar to this:

[image]

If that's not enough current there are many other possibilities, just do a parametric search.